# Clean string javascript function

Tags: javascript, string, function, replace, indexof

This my actual scenario

```
const cleanString=( string )=>{
  let city = getAccentedCity(string);
  if( city.indexOf('%20')<0 ) return city;
  return city.replaceAll('%20', ' ');
  
}
```

I have now to add an other case when a city contains the string `"%c3%9f"` and i want to replace it with `'s'`

How can i add it in my current function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add more tests if you do not want to rewrite the code

```
const cleanString= string => {
  let city = getAccentedCity(string);
  if (city.toLowerCase().indexOf('%c3%9f') >= 0 ) return city.replaceAll('%c3%9f', 's');
  if (city.indexOf('%20') < 0) return city;
  return city.replaceAll('%20', ' ');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all you should be aware that `String.replaceAll()` function is not supported on IE.

If you're ok with it and I assume you are since you're already using it, then I would just create an array of pairs that you can spread into the `replaceAll` function.

Something like this:

```
const replaceMap = [
  ['%20', ' '],
  ['%c3%9f', 's'],
];

const cleanString = (string) => {
  let city = getAccentedCity(string);
  replaceMap.forEach(pair => city = city.replaceAll(...pair));
  return city;
}
```

Comment: Nice one. Liking the spread

Comment: Yes, i have not accepted this answer because there is not the condition when the city does not contain that string. Thanks